# How explode while array with commas in ACF Repeater (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, explode, advanced-custom-fields

ACF Repeater is a plugin to WordPress that creates custom fields. I need to get values separated by commas, but how to do it in a while loop?

This is the code:

```
if( get_field('jobtitles') ) {
    echo '<strong>Jobs: </strong>'; 
        while ( have_rows('jobtitles') ) : the_row();
        echo '<span>'. get_sub_field('jobtitle') .'</span> ';   
        endwhile;
}
```

`the_row` runs through the sub fields of the main field (`job titles`) and get values stores in fieds `jobtitle`. But it echoes like this `Medicine Engineering Geography`, and I need `Medicine, Engineering, Geography`. I found lots of ways to do it using `foreach`, but none to `while` loops.

Comment: I did it, and the question was marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Implode should work:

```
if( get_field('jobtitles') ) {
    echo '<strong>Jobs: </strong>'; 
    while ( have_rows('jobtitles') ) : the_row();
     $array[] = get_sub_field('jobtitles'); 
    endwhile;
    $foo = implode(', ', $array);

    echo $foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) work?

```
if( get_field('jobtitles') ) {
    echo '<strong>Jobs: </strong>'; 
        while ( have_rows('job titles') ) : the_row();
          $jobtitle_array = explode(' ', get_sub_field('jobtitle'); 
          echo '<span>' . implode(', ', $jobtitle_array)  .'</span> ';   
        endwhile;
}
```

Comment: No... don't return anything.

Comment: With the echo. In fact it returns custom fields with this values, so it would be something like: <span>Medicine</span> <span>Engineering</span> <span> Geography</span>.

Comment: Thank you. To make it more clear, the have_rows is a boolean. It's description: "This function checks to see if the field has any rows of data to loop over. This is a boolean function".

Since it doesn't go through the rows, the_row is the tool. "The main difference is that this function (have_rows) does not step through the rows by itself, so to step through the rows, you must also use the the_row function. Using have_rows and the_rows together is intended to feel native to the have_posts and the_posts 'WP loop' idea."

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Not sure if it's the proper, using two "whiles", but it's working:

```
if( get_field('jobtitles') ) {
    $num_rows = 0;
        while ( have_rows('jobtitles') ) : the_row();
        $num_rows++;
        endwhile;

    echo '<strong>Jobs: </strong>';
        while ( have_rows('jobtitles') ) : the_row();
        $num_rows--;
        echo '<span>'. get_sub_field('jobtitle') .'</span>';
        if ( $num_rows == 0 ) { echo '.'; }
        else { echo ', '; }
        endwhile;
}
```

The first while gives plus 1 on var $num_rows. So if I have 10 custom fields, it will finish the loop as $num_rows = 10. The second echoes the values, and on each loop, it checks if the number of rows decreased ($num_row--;). If not, comma on the way and keep going... if yes (end of loop), a dot.

I don't know if it's a good logic, maybe my mind is tired and there are other cleaner ways. But at least works!